# Insert values into multiple rows in one query

Tags: php, postgresql

It's not another lame question as the topic suggests ;). So here's my query:

`CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_tab WITH (OIDS) ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT 22 AS num, 'smth' AS something_else;


SELECT * FROM temp_tab;`

What I'm trying to accomplish is to insert into this temporary table more than one value at a time, like this:

`CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_tab WITH (OIDS) ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT (22, 23, 24) AS num, ('smth', 'wqer', 'asdf') AS something_else;`

The reason why I'm not inserting the data into an ordinary table rather than temp is because I want to use my db to calculate distances between geographical points (postgis), and I have a lot of data - doing this (plus sorting) would be too exhaustive for php and I don't need to store this data - I just want to make some calculations and return the set to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a `VALUES` command as per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createtableas.html, so

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_tab (num integer, something_else char(4))
WITH (OIDS) ON COMMIT DROP AS 
VALUES (22, 'smth'), (23, 'wqer'), (24, 'asdf');
```

*note: I haven't tried the query, so there may be a typo in there, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I'm new to pgsql, so please be patient :). I get this error: syntax error at or near "AS", but the query seems to be ok...

Comment: @marek, It seems that I don't have postgre on my server, so I can't readily test it out... `VALUES` doesn't appear in the docs until v8.2, though. What version are you running?

Comment: @marek, hmmm.... Then it should be supported... the `VALUES` command works in an `INSERT` on MySQL, so there isn't a typo there. Wonder if it's a documented unfeature?

Comment: Yeah, I know, and that's strange for me too. I regret I can't accept your and @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answers at the same time... Ultimately, I'm using two queries - one to create a temp table and second to insert data.

Comment: @marek, If Damien's solution isn't acceptable for you, then you could try filing a bug report at the postgre site...

Comment: Ok, I thought over it and I see now that your solution is exactly what I was looking for, and it's postgres team's fault that it's not working, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use postgresql, but in SQL Server you can build up multiple rows of literals using UNION ALL. Does this work for you?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_tab WITH (OIDS) ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT 22 AS num, 'smth' AS something_else union all
select 23, 'wqer' union all
select 24, 'asdf'
```

Comment: Works like a charm, though I'm worried about performance to of this. Won't calling multiple selects be too tiring for db?

Comment: @marek - if your bottleneck is select performance when there are no source tables being selected from, I think you have more serious problems with your server setup.